# Ruby - Parsing Custom Expressions within a String

Tags: c#, ruby, regex, parsing

I'm working on a phrase generator project. I have a set of vocabulary, and a set of grammar. The "grammar" is just the template statement for which vocabulary will be inserted into. For instance:

The grammar could be: "For Christmas I got a _____!" and the blank would be replaced by a, previously define, randomly selected vocabulary term.

I want a fancier system than just inserting vocab into the string when asked to do so (because that's pretty easy to do).

I want to use a string such as: "For Christmas I got a {fcap(123)}!" Where the curly brackets define a place to insert a generated vocab term, and "fcap" is a method name that uses "123" as its parameters. In this case "fcap" capitalizes the first letter of the generated vocab term.

I'm using Ruby to quickly figure out how to do this in general, I plan on using C# in the final product. I've search many forums, including this one, and failed in all of my own experiments. I really don't even know what this sort of thing is called.

Lastly, I want to be able to do this will much flexibility, so I'd like to have nested methods, and multiple inserts of the curly brackets within the same string. For right now, I'm not gonna allow the vocab to have any functional curly braces to avoid infinite loops.

I'll take any help here, even if it's just pointing me to what/where I should research. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Pleasr make up your mind what language you need an answer for. .NET regex is different from Ruby's.

Comment: The only reason I'm using Ruby is because it's WAY faster to test out concepts than C# is. I'm using it like someone would use pseudo code, so if I can get the answer in Ruby, I'm pretty sure I use a similar solution for C#. I need more of the logic behind performing a complex set of operations like this, rather than the direct code itself. But an example would go a long way.

Comment: I feel that I should mention that the vocab and the grammar that the app will use will be user-defined, which is why I can't just use any built in evaluation methods.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby string interpolation should be enough here:

```
"For Christmas I got a #{fcap(123)}!"
```

beween #{} you can put any ruby expression. It will be evaluated and the answer converted to string and interpolated in the big string.

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm trying to do. I am using ruby as more of a prototyping project, or a proof of concept project. I want to interpolate the string using my own set of methods so that when I switch back to C#, I know, more or less, what I need to do. My problem seems to be in how I'm using recursion. Then again, if I could figure out how to easily integrate Ruby into a C#, windows application project, I would probably take that route instead of doing it all from scratch.